# spdlog: not configuring the logger correctly using same sink

Tags: c++, spdlog

The following code :

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"

int main() {
  auto stdout_sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>();
  auto a = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("a", stdout_sink);
  auto b = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("b", stdout_sink);

  a->set_pattern("%v");
  b->set_pattern("debug %v");

  a->info("a");
  b->info("b");
}
```

outputs

```
debug a
debug b
```

rather than

```
  a
 debug b
```

It seems as though the spdlogger only remembers the last registered pattern. How do I achieve the intended as in having two loggers with different patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That would work yes. Problem is when you want to extend this to log files. Then, you end up having two log files

The answer is you can't, *directly*.

`set_formatter` is just a wrapper of [`set_formatter(pattern_formatter{})`](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/128cbe5a06051e0bc43d90c2434f7f68a2900587/include/spdlog/logger-inl.h#L101-L105). In spdlog, a formatter is [stored](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/128cbe5a06051e0bc43d90c2434f7f68a2900587/include/spdlog/logger-inl.h#L82-L99) in a `sink` rather than a `logger`.

---

Just thought of a workaround if you really need this feature.

You can [implement](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/4.-Sinks#implementing-your-own-sink) your own `file_sink`, and then you can have multiple `formatter`s.

There is a field [`logger_name`](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/128cbe5a06051e0bc43d90c2434f7f68a2900587/include/spdlog/details/log_msg.h#L20) in struct `log_msg`, you can use it to determine which logger the message came from, and use a different formatter. Note that if you did not set a name for a logger, the field is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cpp
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"

int main() {
  auto stdout_sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>();
  auto stdout_sink_b = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>();
  auto a = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("a", stdout_sink);
  auto b = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("b", stdout_sink_b);

  a->set_pattern("%v");
  b->set_pattern("debug %v");

  a->info("a");
  b->info("b");
}
```

The output is:

```sh
a
debug b
```

Comment: That would work yes. Problem is when you want to extend this to log files. Then, you end up having two log files

Comment: Do you mean this case: https://github.com/gabime/spdlog#logger-with-multi-sinks---each-with-different-format-and-log-level?